Proof of inequality involving matrices: $\operatorname{tr}(I-\Lambda) + \log \det \Lambda \leq 0$
Notation
Let $I_n$ be an $n$th order unit matrix.
Problem
We want to show that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(I_n-\Lambda) + \log \det \Lambda \leq 0,
$$
where $n\times n$ matrix $\Lambda$ is a positive definite matrix.
What I know
For any $\lambda >0$, the inequality
$$
\log \lambda \leq \lambda - 1
$$
is valid.
Furthermore,
$$
\log\det A = \operatorname{tr}\log A
$$
is also known to hold.
In this case, the LHS of the inequality we want to show can be transformed as follows:
$$
\operatorname{tr}(I_n-\Lambda) + \log \det \Lambda = \operatorname{tr}(I_n-\Lambda) + \operatorname{tr}\log \Lambda = \operatorname{tr}(I_n-\Lambda + \log\Lambda).
$$
I am almost ready to show it, but what should I do from here?

You're extremely close. I think you're only missing to consider the eigenvalues and remember how trace is related to eigenvalues

In $\operatorname{det}(\Lambda)=\prod^n_{j=1}\lambda_j$ where $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq \ldots\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $\Lambda$ (all of which are positive by assumption.

What are the eigenvalues of $I - \Lambda + \log \Lambda$?

You are on the right track. Now, you have :
$$
\operatorname{tr}(I_n-\Lambda + \log\Lambda) = \sum_k \left(\log\lambda_k - (\lambda_k-1)\right) \le 0,
$$
since $\log\lambda_k \le \lambda_k-1$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ of $\Lambda$.
